# Fullcalendar count events of current day by property

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am using fullcalendar version 4.  When the current day has events that are changed in some way, I want to update a separate part of my page with the counts of the events: how many are unconfirmed, how many are confirmed, how many cancelled, etc. for a certain date (called call_list_date) in my code.

I was wondering if there was a way to do this using one of fullcalendar's methods?  I currently am using the eventrender to count what I need, but I'm finding that event render is fired and the counts are updated even when I resize, hover an event over the current date, and so on.

Is there a callback or something I can use within fullcalendar that is fired ONLY when an event is re-rendered/dropped/added after a definite change has been made by the user to the event.

Here's what I am using to update my counts:

```
eventRender: function(info) {

            //update call list counts if event on same date
            //only update call list if call list date = date of event!
            var call_list_date = moment($('#call_date').data('call_date_to_pass')).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            var event_date = moment(info.event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');


            if (call_list_date == event_date) {


                var appt_status = info.event.extendedProps.appt_status_id;
                var post_appt_status = info.event.extendedProps.post_appt_status_id;

                //unconfirmed
                if ((appt_status == '2' || appt_status == '9' ||
                    appt_status == '10')  && post_appt_status == null)  {

                    var this_number = $('#unconfirmed_count').text();
                    if (!this_number) {
                        this_number = 0;
                    }
                    var unconfirmed_count = parseInt(this_number);
                    var new_unconfirmed_count = unconfirmed_count + 1;

                    $('#unconfirmed_count').text(new_unconfirmed_count);

                }

                //confirmed
                if (appt_status == '1' && post_appt_status == null)  {

                    var this_number = $('#confirmed_count').text();
                    if (!this_number) {
                        this_number = 0;
                    }
                    var confirmed_count = parseInt(this_number);
                    var new_confirmed_count = confirmed_count + 1;

                    $('#confirmed_count').text(new_confirmed_count);

                }
```

Comment: there are separate callbacks you can use to detect when events are resized, dragged, or dropped on the calendar. And if you're allowing users to select areas to add new events, or click them to edit the data, or delete them, then those are other places where you might want to update the counter. There's no one catch-all callback to detect all those things, instead there are several separate handlers you need to use. Of course if you put your counter update code into a separate function which just accepts relevant data as the input, then you can re-use the same function from all those places

Comment: Thanks for responding, ADyson.  I understand what you're saying, and I'll take all this into account to make it work.  

I appreciate your help with all my fullcalendar questions so far.